# Followup Q: Compare Rows in Oracle Table and update Matching Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I asked the following a week ago:

[Compare Rows in oracle table and update matching ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656784/compare-rows-in-oracle-table-and-update-matching-ones/43662026#43662026)

I received excellent helpful answers, but i am stuck again, as i need to amend the answers received, and add another filter.

On top of having different BuySell fields, there is a Description field that cannot be equal. 
Unlike BuySell field that can only take two values, Description can be anything.

Following is the answer by @MT0 i have been using, and that i hope to amend:

```
MERGE INTO your_table dst 
USING (   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY tDate, Product, Price, Quantity, BuySell
             ORDER BY ID
           ) AS idx,
         COUNT( CASE BuySell WHEN 'Buy' THEN 1 END ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY tDate, Product, Price, Quantity
           ) AS num_buy,
         COUNT( CASE BuySell WHEN 'Sell' THEN 1 END ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY tDate, Product, Price, Quantity
           ) AS num_sell   FROM   your_table

) src ON ( src.ROWID = dst.ROWID AND src.idx <= LEAST( src.num_buy, src.num_sell ) ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN   UPDATE SET Status = 'Matched';
```

EDIT:
Following is an example

I have a table such as the following:

```
**ID      tDate       Product   Description  Price    Quantity    BuySell    Status**
  1     10-May-17       pppp       p1        $12        20         Buy       Null
  2     12-May-17       tttt       t1        $10        20         Sell      Null
  3     12-May-17       tttt       t2        $10        20         Buy       Null
  4     18-May-17       pppp       p2        $14        20         Sell      Null
  5     18-May-17       pppp       p3        $14        20         Buy       Null
  6     19-May-17       xxxx       x4        $11        10         Sell      Null
  7     19-May-17       xxxx       x4        $11        10         Buy       Null
```

I need to update the field named STATUS, and set it to 'Matched', wherever a pair is found with equal tDate, product, price, and quantity, and NOT equal BuySell AND Description.

Following is the desired result:

```
**ID      tDate       Product   Description  Price    Quantity    BuySell    Status**
  1     10-May-17       pppp      p1         $12        20         Buy       Null
  2     12-May-17       tttt      t1         $10        20         Sell      Matched
  3     12-May-17       tttt      t2         $10        20         Buy       Matched
  4     18-May-17       pppp      p2         $14        20         Sell      Matched
  5     18-May-17       pppp      p3         $14        20         Buy       Matched
  6     19-May-17       xxxx      x4         $11        10         Sell      Null
  7     19-May-17       xxxx      x4         $11        10         Buy       Null
```

Notice that 6 and 7 did not match because they have the same Description.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] - i.e. some sample data and your expected output (and, if it is not obvious, a description of the logic used to generate that output).

Comment: @MT0 just edited the question

Comment: So do you want to match Buy - Sell pairs that have different descriptions: what happens if you have two buys with the same description (D1) and two sells with another (D2)? That could give you two identical pairs - (buy D1, sell D2), (buy D1, sell D2) where the description is different inside the pair. Do you want to match these or not?

Comment: @Mike If there is one buy row that matches three sell rows (with non-equal descriptions) then all four rows will be updated with that solution. The OP states that the rows should be matched in pairs (so, in the hypothetical situation I described only the buy row and one of the three sell rows should be updated while the other two sell rows, when there is no matched pair, should not).

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
   set status='Matched'
 where id in(
    with IDS(id1,id2,grp,num,rnum) as(
     select a.id,b.id,
            rank() over(order by a.tdate,a.price,a.product,a.quantity),
            case when a.id=lag(a.id) over(partition by a.tdate,a.price,a.product,a.quantity order by a.id)
            then 0
            else dense_rank() over(partition by a.tdate,a.price,a.product,a.quantity order by a.id) end,
            row_number() over(partition by a.tdate,a.price,a.product,a.quantity order by a.id)
       from your_table a, your_table b
      where a.tdate=b.tdate and a.price=b.price and a.product=b.product 
        and a.quantity=b.quantity
        and a.buysell='Sell' and b.buysell='Buy' and a.description!=b.description
    ),
    Q(id1,id2,grp,num,used) as(
      select id1,id2,grp,num,','||id2||','
        from IDS where rnum=1
      union all
      select I.id1,R.column_value,Q.grp,Q.num+1,Q.used||R.column_value||','
        from Q, IDS I,
             table(cast(multiset(
                select min(id2) id from IDS N
                 where N.id1=I.id1
                   and Q.used not like '%,'||N.id2||',%'
             ) as sys.ODCINumberList)) R
       where I.grp=Q.grp and I.num=Q.num+1
    )
 select decode(X,1,id1,id2)
   from Q,
        (select 1 X from DUAL union all select 2 from DUAL)
  where id2 is not null
)
```